# Decompose time series in R on weekly basis

Tags: r, time-series

I want to decompose time Series into seasonality and trend in R.My data looks like this:
Day column:It has name of day
Volume column:It indicate sales

```
  Day Volume (Units)
       Sun   41,806,
       Mon   41,913 
       Tues  43,524 
       Wed   46,765 
       Thurs     39,701 
       Fri   39,492 
       Sat   40,663 
       Sun   78,000 
       Mon   75,000 
       Tues  65,000 
       Wed   38,500 
       Thurs     38,100 
       Fri   37,500 
       Sat   37,600
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? What is your intended output? Perhaps you could make this a little more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), and show what effort you have done before asking here.

Comment: My intede output is :https://www.google.co.in/search?q=decompose+time+series&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwicyeSRkq7VAhXJRo8KHTn6BrkQ_AUICigB&biw=1366&bih=613#imgrc=EmqMPgRtZQ3-NM:

Comment: I assume you've already tried `decompose()`, so what issues did you encounter?